# How to embed OpenSocial Gadget

Tags: opensocial

I have a gadget in Jira dashboard.
Could anyone clearly and simply explain how I can display the gadget on my html page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a Jira gadget on your own html page, your site must be an OpenSocial container. Try downloading and running the reference container Apache Shindig.

If you want to use gadgets that access protected resources (like "My Activity"), then you will also need to implement OAuth consumer features to consume resources on your Jira server (the OAuth producer). I can't remember right now if there's a working consumer implementation out of the box. Register your website as an external application on Jira, setup the proper consumer keys and you should be good to go.